# Symfony gedmo translatable not working

Tags: php, symfony, translation

This is my config.yml:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    auto_mapping: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    mappings:
        gedmo_translatable:
            type: annotation
            prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
            dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity/MappedSuperclass"
            alias: GedmoTranslatable
            is_bundle: false
    filters:
        softdeleteable:
            class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
            enabled: true
        product_category_filter:
            class: AppBundle\Bundle\CoreBundle\Doctrine\Filter\CategoryFilter
            enabled: false
```

This is the annotation part of my entity that needs translation:

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\TranslationEntity(class="AppBundle\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Translation\ProductCategory")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Repository\ProductCategoryRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_categories")
 * @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("none")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false)
 */
```

This is the annotation part of the translation entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_category_translations", indexes={
 *      @ORM\Index(name="product_category_translation_idx", columns={"locale", "object_class", "field", "foreign_key"})
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\Repository\TranslationRepository")
 */
```

But when I do:

```
$category->getTitle()
```

I always the english (non-translated) value, even when my locale is different.

Someone has an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Or am I missing a crucial part of info/code in my question?

PS: I'm using symfony 2.8

Answer (score 2):

you need to activate it in your config.yml:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
  default_locale: "%locale%"
  translation_fallback: false
  orm:
    default:
        translatable: true
```